Java Unmarshalling error, namespace issue. Package-info changes
I have created a SOAP client request to consume a web service. The web service hosting team is expecting a request something like this with the below namespace.
<revisionRequest xmlns = "urn:com.hr.app.sync/1.0"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns2 = "http://www.tibco.com/schemas/pre_pdm_indicenter/Resources/Schema/Revisionpublishresponse.xsd"
    xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <header></header>
</revisionRequest

But they are receiving request from my end as below.
<ns4:revisionRequest
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.asml.com/Services/Revision/LoadRevision/Service/SOAP/Revision"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns4="urn:com.hr.app.sync/1.0"
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/pre_pdm_indicenter/Resources/Schema/Revisionpublishresponse.xsd">
    <header></header>
</revisionRequest>

The header element is not getting the namespace. I understand the issue, that i need to remove the namespace prefix  from the revisionrequest to make it look like the expected one or add the namespace to header element. I have already made the package-info changes, but its still not working and giving marshalling error.
